# How to make u-boot to switch to Hypervisor mode instead of svc mode

Tags: u-boot, hypervisor

I am currently working on Hypervisor on one of the freescale boards, In general 
    u-boot once booted after reset will move to svc mode, as i am using hypervisor now.
    I have to move to hypervisor mode instead of svc mode.
    How u-boot move to hypervisor mode, whether we need to write the extra code or
    this support is already present in the source code.

```
Thank You
```

Comment: Can you please clarify which SoC / platform you're working on?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at arch/arm/cpu/armv8/fwcall.c in mainline U-Boot today, you will need to add support for what you're doing here.  Thanks!